# How to register multiple KeyEvent triggers in wxPython

Tags: python, event-handling, wxpython

I'm currently using wxPython to develop an interactive application; in which, I would like to retain and repeat the last used key pressed.  An example of what I'm trying to attain is:

[key 'a' pressed and held][key 'b' pressed and held][key 'b' released][key 'a' released]

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

I can't seem to be able to find a way to manually trigger an event like this, I've attempted to use wx.PostEvent, but am either using it incorrectly or it isn't what I'm needing, since technically a key_down event hasn't fired when the second group of 'a's should be registering, and I can't find out how to fire a key_down event with a specific value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option in cases like this is to poll the [key state](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#GetKeyState) yourself in a loop. If key 'a' is pressed then call your action

Answer (score 2):

When you want to catch multi-key events, you have two options. You can catch EVT_CHAR or you can create an Accelerator Table. Here's an article where I attempted to explain how EVT_CHAR works: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/29/wxpython-catching-key-and-char-events/

Here's another article on Accelerator Tables: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/12/02/wxpython-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/

With the former, you might be able to "record" what was pressed. I don't know why you'd want to do that. I don't think wxPython provides a way to replay keys pressed. On Windows, there's a 3rd party module called SendKeys that you might be able to use for this: http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/

If none of this helps, please ask on the official wxPython mailing list / Google Group. Those guys can probably help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Catch key up/Down events and acts accordingly. 
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxkeyevent.html
http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.KeyEvent-class.html

Comment: That works fine for SINGLE key_up, key_down, or char events, the issue is that it technically has no memory, so after I press and hold the first key_down, if I press a second w/o removing the first, [b]there's no way to re-fire the first key_down[/b] which is the crux of the problem.  A single keyEvent cannot handle this, and has no documentation as such.